# How set a Session variable expired time on MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to Generate a Verification Code like: **1599** for Login.

The User must input correct number when Login in.

But My default session expired time is **30 minute**.

I don't want let the Verification Code expired time so long. I just need it keep only **1 minute**.
So How I set expired time out only for the Verification Code session variable?

**Update1:**

> I don't want to change the global session expired time. I just need
>   set only for the Verification Code session variable before login.

Comment: Good and useful question, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry guys, I finally use this solution:

when generate the Verification Code I will save it to session

```
Session["VerificationCode"] = code;
```

That's everybody knows. but how about the time? I change it :

```
Session["VerificationCode"] = code;
Session["VerificationTime"] = DateTime.Now;
```

Now **the time save in session** too. Then I can find it when User Login:

```
 // Verification Code Expired
 if ((DateTime)Session["VerificationTime"]).AddMinutes(1) < DateTime.Now)
 {
       ModelState.AddModelError("VerificationCode", "Verification Code Expired!");
       return View(adminLogin);
 }
 // Verification Code Error
 if (Session["VerificationCode"].ToString().ToUpper() != adminLogin.VerificationCode.ToUpper())
 {
       ModelState.AddModelError("VerificationCode", "Verification Code Error");
       return View(adminLogin);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no built-in way, BUT you can achieve it very simple:

```
Session[name] = value;

//now add a cleanup task that will run after the specified interval
Task.Delay(expireAfter).ContinueWith((task) => {
    Session.Remove(name);
});
```

I wrapped this into a very handy "session extender" class [source code here](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/196-aspnet-session-caching-expiring-values/) you can use it like this:

```
//store and expire after 5 minutes
Session.AddWithTimeout("key", "value", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

PS. If you're still using an old .NET version (no async code, no tasks) you'll find a compatible version in my blogpost as well.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a class or structure that is stored in SessionState rather than just storing the verification code itself.  This will allow you to easily check the code and the expiration date of the code.

E.g.:

```
public class VerificationCode {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
}

// in your method
VerificationCode newCode = new VerificationCode {
                                         Code="1559",
                                         ExpirationDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)
                                     };
Session["VerificationCode"] = newCode;


// in the method where you check the expiration date and code...
VerificationCode code = (VerificationCode)Session["VerificationCode"];

// you can remove the verification code after pulling it out, as you only need
//  it once, regardless of whether it is still good or expired.
Session.Remove("VerificationCode");

if (code.ExpirationDate < System.DateTime.Now){
   // the verification code expired...

   // can remove the verification code after successful login
   Session.Remove("VerificationCode");
} else {
  // verification code is still good.
  // Log the user in?

  // can remove the verification code after successful login
  Session.Remove("VerificationCode");
}
```

**Updated**
- Added removal of verification code from session when expired OR upon successful login.
- square bracket accessor for Session variables. Previously used VB (doh!) syntax (parentheses)

Comment: It seems condition line must be "if (code.ExpirationDate < System.DateTime.Now){ }"

Comment: Thanks @QMaster. I fixed it.

Comment: Your Welcome :) Thanks to you.

Comment: I had some remnants of VB syntax in there, lol. Thanks again, @QMaster

Comment: That's usual for programmers dud ;) Welcome again :D

Answer (score 2):

You can't change session time for one particular case. Instead you can use [Cache.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780614(v=vs.110).aspx) method with `absoluteExpiration` parameter to store `VerificationCode` in the `Cache`.

```
MemoryCache.Default.Add([UserIdentity], [Verification Code], 
    new DateTimeOffset().ToOffset(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)));
```

And then get it from `Cache`

```
var verificationCode = MemoryCache.Default.Remove([UserIdentity]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**SESSION STATE SETTINGS**

By default ASP.NET uses cookies to identify which requests belong to a particular session. If cookies are not available, a session can be tracked by adding a session identifier to the URL. To disable cookies, set `sessionState cookieless="true".` But this will change the setting for the all the sessions available for the application.

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="120"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

References : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525473%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

---

In your case you can use cookie to track and set it to expire after 1 Minute , I can give you an example like:

```
Response.Cookies["userName"].Value = "patrick";
Response.Cookies["userName"].Expires =DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("lastVisit");
aCookie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```